# How to return a[0:len(a)-2] with write a only once in python?

Tags: python-2.7

From this lines, we get '12345'

```
a = '1234567' 
a[0:len(a)-2]
```

How to do it with writing 'a' only once?

I Got it. The answer is

```
a[:-2]
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are asking. Do you only want to output a single digit?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, just use the - sign. - can truncate the string from the tail.

```
a[:-2]
```